# Using Haskell's MVar package but enforcing strictness with seq

Tags: multithreading, haskell

Under the `Control.Concurrent.MVar` documentation on hackage, we have a 'gotcha' regarding the usage of `MVar`s. Here's the [link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html).

MVar says that when you use `putMVar` to put something in an `MVar`, if that thing you're putting in is a huge thunk, the receiving thread will have the messy job of evaluation, not the sending thread.

Apart from that being potentially annoying or unwarranted, to remedy such a situation it points us in the direction of `evaluate` which itself says to use `seq`. Everyone's favourite haskell function.

[Evaluate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate)'s semantics are supposedly meant to be like this:

> ```
> evaluate x `seq` y    ==>  y
> ```

So my question is: why won't this evaluate in the forked thread!?!?!

```
concTreeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> IO (BinaryTree b)
concTreeMap f Leaf = return Leaf
concTreeMap f (Branch v l r) =  do
  res <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do
              let fv = f v
              evaluate fv `seq` (putMVar res fv)
  v' <- takeMVar res
  l' <- concTreeMap f l
  r' <- concTreeMap f r
  return (Branch v' l' r')
```

Edited to add an equivalent speedup...

Somehow this is equivalent to the answer below (not using evaluate but using seq)... Anyway I think the point of the speed up is in a) providing a hint to the haskell runtime about thunk evaluation and 2) moving the take away from the put

```
concTreeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> IO (BinaryTree b)
concTreeMap f Leaf = return Leaf
concTreeMap f (Branch v l r) =  do
  res <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do { let fv = f v in fv `seq` putMVar res fv }
  l' <- concTreeMap f l
  r' <- concTreeMap f r
  v' <- takeMVar res
  return (Branch v' l' r')
```

Comment: That equation you quoted is exactly saying that ``evaluate `seq` y`` is the same as `y`, i.e., your use of `evaluate` does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you fixed your program as in Petr Pudlák's answer, you're trying to take from the `MVar` immediately after starting the thread to put a value in it. So you have no parallelism since the thread running `concTreeMap` has to wait for the `MVar` to be full, which means waiting for the forked thread to put `fv` in the `MVar`, which it doesn't do until after it has evaluated it. Meanwhile the original thread is doing nothing.

Didn't you mean to write

```
  ...
  forkIO $ do
              let fv = f v
              evaluate fv `seq` (putMVar res fv)
  l' <- concTreeMap f l
  r' <- concTreeMap f r
  v' <- takeMVar res         -- Note: this moved to after we do more work
  return (Branch v' l' r')
```

?

Comment: You're a living legend. Now how to I cash out the points to both of you haha?!?!?

Answer (score 5):

Because you used `seq` to force the evaluation of `evaluate fv`. This is an `IO` action, and *evaluating* it is something completely different than *running* it.

If you think of an `IO` action as a recipe, running `seq` on it, evaluating it, is just making sure the recipe is fully written down, but running is actually using the recipe to produce something.

The forked part should be instead

```
forkIO $ do
          let fv = f v
          evaluate fv
          putMVar res fv
```

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but this is still slower than not doing it concurrently. I also feel like you may not have enough information in the question to diagnose this issue, though... Hmm

Comment: @lol How do you measure the speed? How complex is your `f`? Are you sure that the concurrency overhad (switching CPU contexts, using `MVar`s isn't greater than the gain from parallelization?

Comment: `f` is a factorial function, I'm timing it with `time` and for googlers that make it here ever, remember to compile with `ghc -threaded`, control for `O1`, `O2`, etc. in your tests

Comment: @lol Sounds good.  Somewhat more accurate measurement than `time` is provided by [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).